# awk to fetch two values in a file

Tags: shell, awk

Input file:

```
2012/01/18 11:24 GMT+00:00   adm   Add  "/david/admin"  "/apps/data/unix/archives/osn/admin"    ""
```

I did

```
awk -F'"' print {$2"}' /file/path
```

and I got

```
/david/admin
```

and

```
awk -F'"' print {$4"}
```

got me

```
/apps/data/unix/archives/osn/admin
```

Is there to combine these and store them in individual variable?

Example:

```
name=/david/admin
path=/apps/data/unix/archives/osn/admin
```

Comment: Please be careful with your scripts.  Both the `awk` fragments you show should lead to secondary prompts from the shell because of incomplete strings.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store them in awk variables, you're basically done:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{ name=$2;path=$4 } { print name }' <<< '2012/01/18 11:24 GMT+00:00 adm Add "/david/admin" "/apps/data/unix/archives/osn/admin" ""'
/david/admin
```

If you want to store them in shell variables, use `read` instead of awk.

```
$ IFS='"' read _ name _ path _ <<< '2012/01/18 11:24 GMT+00:00 adm Add "/david/admin" "/apps
/data/unix/archives/osn/admin" ""'
$ echo $name
/david/admin
$ echo $path
/apps/data/unix/archives/osn/admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of typo in your awk, as written above, they does not give what you tell they are giving.
Wrong `awk -F'"' print {$4"}` correct `awk -F'"' '{print $4}'`. 
Here is how I would store to shell variable.

```
name=$(awk -F\" '{print $2}' file)
path=$(awk -F\" '{print $4}' file)
```